# How do I assign the post parent?

Tags: custom-post-types, hierarchical

I am trying to connect two custom post types. Through lots of googling, I found the following code that adds a meta box to the admin screen to select a post from another post type as the parent, but how do I set that post as the parent in the database?

```
add_action('admin_menu', function() {
    remove_meta_box('pageparentdiv', 'episodes', 'normal');
});
add_action('add_meta_boxes', function() {
    add_meta_box('episodes-parent', 'Cartoon Series', 'episodes_attributes_meta_box', 'episodes', 'side', 'default');
});

function episodes_attributes_meta_box($post) {
    $post_type_object = get_post_type_object($post->post_type);
    if ( $post_type_object->hierarchical ) {
        $pages = wp_dropdown_pages(array('post_type' => 'cartoon-series', 'selected' => $post->post_parent, 'name' => 'parent_id', 'show_option_none' => __('(no parent)'), 'sort_column'=> 'menu_order, post_title', 'echo' => 0));
        if ( ! empty($pages) ) {
            echo $pages;
        } // end empty pages check
    } // end hierarchical check.
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you need the parent - child relationship in the database ?

Comment: According to another post I had on here, I was not setting the parent anywhere. I assumed he meant I needed to save the parent in the database. I have the metabox to select a parent. Now how do I preserve that setting?

Comment: Nevermind, I see on my other thread that the guy says he was mistaken and I was doing it correctly already. I'm just getting 404 errors. See here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/181134/why-am-i-getting-a-404-when-viewing-a-post-with-a-page-parent

Comment: This problem was solved under a broader topic here:
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/181134/why-am-i-getting-a-404-when-viewing-a-post-with-a-page-parent?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `save_post` hook to handle your meta box and set the post_parent field of the post.

An alternative aproch is to look at the page edit page and check what is the name of the "parent page" drop down and use the same for your dropdown instead of the `parent_id` you use right now.

Comment: As far as I can tell, parent_id is the name of the dropdown on a typical parent page selector. I had this set up before, but I was getting 404 errors on the page. See this thread: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/181134/why-am-i-getting-a-404-when-viewing-a-post-with-a-page-parent
Oh, I see you already have! :-)

Comment: If it doesn't work with `parent_id` then you need to handle it explicitly in the hook. the other question is not realy related to this one, you can create whatever connection you want between the posts, you don't have to use the wordpress way if you don't gain anything from it (but I assume you can gain, so you are not wasting your time on this IMHO)

Comment: The problem was resolved in my other, similar thread.