# How to make a posttype show under a page hierarchy (example.com/page/posttype/entry)?

Tags: custom-post-types, slug

I have a page, say streets, which is a static page and has the slug `example.com/streets/`, and I want to have many single streets under it. Let these streets be called `streetdetails`, so a single street detail would be `example.com/streets/streetdetails/1`.

When I create a posttype with Custom Post UI, I always get just top level slugs, such as `example.com/streetdetails/1` and I cannot use the frontbase option either, as this is `blog` and will create false slugs.

How can I get that page -> posttype setup, that will put a posttype hierarchically under a page slug?

Comment: i think this what you searching for 
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/181134/how-to-set-parent-child-relationship-between-differents-custom-post-types , sorry for my poor english

Comment: Use `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'streets/streetdetails', 'with_front' => false )` in your register arguments. Make sure to re-save permalinks in the admin after making the code change.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Thanks, that worked. If you add this as answer, I will choose it as the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to alter your rewrite arguments in your `register_post_type()` call:

```
'rewrite' => array(
    'slug'       => 'streets/streetdetails',
    'with_front' => false,
);
```

Make sure to re-save permalinks in the admin after making the code change.